# Join on two columns in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join, inner-join

I have two tables:

**website_table**

```
name | url
a    | www.a.com
b    | www.b.com
c    | www.c.com
```

**dependency_table**

```
name_1 | name_2
a      | b
a      | c
```

*Basically saying `a` depends on both `b` and `c`*

I need to do an SQL join on these tables to get a table in the form

```
name_1 | name_2 | url_1     | url_2
a      | b      | www.a.com | www.b.com
a      | c      | www.a.com | www.c.com
```

So I have each dependency with its website `url` information,

Can this be done in one query?

Comment: Have you tried writing the query?  You should include your attempts at solving the problem.

Comment: All my attempts ended up with an "Every derived table must have it's own alias" error so I didn't think they would be much use

Comment: Actually that is incredibly helpful, that means you probably have a syntax issue that could easily be resolved by _seeing_ the query.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
SELECT dt.name_1, 
       dt.name_2, 
       wt1.url AS url_1, 
       wt2.url AS url_2
FROM dependency_table dt 
INNER JOIN website_table wt1 ON dt.name_1 = wt1.name
INNER JOIN website_table wt2 ON dt.name_2 = wt2.name;
```